# console.log(req) displays database data

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, npm, express-session

I ran a `console.log(req);` to see what was there and found that the data from the DB is shown together with the session data

```js
sessionStore: MySQLStore {
    . . .
    options: {
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '1324',
      database: 'dbso',
      endConnectionOnClose: true,
      clearExpired: true,
      checkExpirationInterval: 900000,
      expiration: 86400000,
      createDatabaseTable: true,
      connectionLimit: 1,
      charset: 'utf8mb4_bin',
      schema: [Object]
    }, . . .
```

I am working with `express-mysql-session` and `express-session`

```js
app.use(session({
    secret: "sss",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new mySQLStore({ /*Database info*/ })
}));
```

My concern and doubt is how much I should worry about this, and if I should worry about it, how can I solve it?

Our site uses cookies to store user sessions.

The summary of my doubt is, can the req become viewable/obtainable from the user side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The summary of my doubt is, can the req become viewable/obtainable from the user side?

No.

The request object is used to pass data between middleware and end point handlers. It is only visible on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing calling `console.log` from the node process. Unless you are doing something very strange (eg sending this  `req` object back to client via say http), this will not be visible from client side.

Answer (score 0):

If it makes you feel better, that has been there 8 years in express-session, see [this](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blame/a8641429502fcc076c4b2dcbd6b2320891c1650c/index.js#L214),
it's completely intentional, and nobody's has complained.

I think it's only added to the `req` that you recieve. but the client side has no access to it